# Cannot read property 'metadata' of null Nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongodb, ejs

This is my error:

```
 TypeError: Cannot read property 'metadata' of null
 at gfs.files.findOne (M:\FinalProject\Commerce\routes\index.js:187:13)
 at result (M:\FinalProject\Commerce\node_modules\mongodb\lib\utils.js:414:17)
```

This is my code :

```
    router.get('/:filename', (req,res) => {
    const img = req.params.filename; // Filename
     gfs.files.findOne({filename: img}, (req,file) =>{


  if(file.metadata.brand=="Mango"){
  const brand = "Mango";
   displayOne(brand);
  }
  else if(file.metadata.brand=="Cocotail")
  {
  const brand = "Cocotail";
   displayOne(brand);
  }
  else if(file.metadata.brand==null)
  {  
   console.log("Null");

   }




   function displayOne(brand)
    {
   gfs.files.find({'metadata.brand': brand }).toArray((err,files)=>{

   if(!file || file.length ===0)
   {
   return res.status(404).json({
    err: 'No files exist'
   });
  }

   if(file.contentType === 'image/jpeg' || file.contentType === 'image/png')
  {

   file.isImage = true;
   }
   else
  {
  res.status(404).json({
    err: 'Not an image'
  });
  file.isImage = false;
  }


   res.render('singleproduct',{
    file:file,
    relatedProduct:files, // Related Products
    isSearch:0

  });
  });

  }

 });
 });
```

Please give me any ideas about this error. i couldn't find out what is the major reason for this error. I searched  on google but there are no appropriate solutions for that.____________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________

Thank you

Comment: Which line is line 187? The immediate problem would probably be that `file` in `file.metadata` is null, which means (I think) that `findOne()` didn't find one...

Comment: if(file.metadata.brand=="Mango"){

Comment: Can you recommend me how to show related products when user click a product. this code mainly executes to get related product items

Comment: That means `file` is `null`. The error is happening somewhere before this line, when variable `file` is being populated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you console what you get just above

> (file.metadata.brand=="Mango")

in file? seems you don't get any data from

> gfs.files.findOne({filename: img}

try this:

```
 if(file && file.metadata.brand=="Mango"){
  const brand = "Mango";
   displayOne(brand);
  }
  else if(file && file.metadata.brand=="Cocotail")
  {
  const brand = "Cocotail";
   displayOne(brand);
  }
  else if(file && file.metadata.brand==null)
  {  
   console.log("Null");

   }
else{
    console.log("didinot find value")
}
```

Comment: I got the result                                                                                                            const img = req.params.filename; -> Here i get the image filename                                      gfs.files.findOne({filename: img}, (req,file) =>{   -> I searched on database by using img

Comment: gfs.files.findOne({filename: img}) is this the part where you get data from your collection? 
you are not getting data in variable file from db.

Comment: No ! i got the data from the collection. The problem is when i render another page it will show errors that i have shown above. I didn't understand that why this error shows on another rendering .

Comment: see the error says "metadata of null" and metadata is in object 'file'. can you share the data you get from db?

Comment: can you check my latest question ?